# what is the use of Store on disk in tMap component?

Tags: talend

what is the use of Store on disk in tMap component??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6dbg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option allow you to store data in disk in order to process them in the job. If you don't use that option the data will be load in RAM and not in the disk. Sometime you don't have enought memory in the RAM so you check this option in order to make the disk work instead of RAM (More space).

The disavantage of that is that is slower than the default "in RAM" processing.